# Why are some minor update versions of Java skipped?

Tags: java, software-updates

Up until around January 2013, the minor updates of major Java versions were always consecutive: 6u30, 6u31, 6u32, 6u33 and so on. The same is true for Java 7 updates.

But, starting around January or February 2013, some minor version numberings were skipped. Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_7_updates As you can see, the minor updates are 7u10, 7u11, 7u13, 7u15, 7u17, 7u21, 7u25. Where did 7u12, 7u14, 7u16 etc. dissapear ? Was there a specific reason why they were skipped ?

If they were actually faulty and couldn't be released, then:

- how come there is no significant uptake in the time-gap between them ?
- how come up until January/February this year this never happened, but is constantly happening ever since ?

I tried searching for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything. So I thought someone here might have a clue about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Orace has adopted a [pretty weird numbering scheme](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/jdk-version-number-scheme-1918258.html):

> Since the initial release of JDK 5.0, Java update releases have either
> been Limited Update releases that include new functionality and
> non-security fixes or Critical Patch Updates (CPUs) that only include
> fixes for security vulnerabilities. We will continue releasing Limited
> Update and CPU Java releases, however we are changing the frequency
> and way in which these releases are numbered:
>
> - Limited Update releases will be numbered in multiples of 20.
> - We intend for Critical Patch Updates to continue to use odd numbers. The numbers will be calculated by adding multiples of five to the
>   prior Limited Update and when needed adding one to keep the resulting
>   number odd.
>
> [...]
>
> This numbering scheme will leave several numbers between releases which will allow us to insert releases – for example security alerts or support releases, should that become necessary - without having to renumber later releases.